# How to get Relative Path from Files of one chosen Folder?

Tags: c#, path, directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij5yM.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04F12.png)
I get only the relative path of the directory/folders but not of the files in it? I can't really find the bug... . I do not understand why it won't get the relative path of the files but of the folders it will.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the code inline, instead of a screenshot? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx) :

Directory.GetFiles Method (String)

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified directory.

So you should do this:

```
foreach(string filename in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
    result.Append(Path.GetFileName(filename), "FILE");
}
```